# Gradle - different lib versions in compileClasspath and runtimeClassPath

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDE for a gradle project. I have added a few dependencies from other projects. To test a change, I changed the versions of a few of those dependencies, some to lower version. These are added as 'implementation' and do have inter dependencies.

Run the individual test classes => success

Gradle build => IncompatibleClassChangeError due to the use of wrong version

CompileClassPath versions => correct

RuntimeClassPath versions => incorrect

Is my gradle build failing due to the wrong versions at runtime? How do I make sure my runtime and compile lib versions are in sync?

Thanks.

Comment: You can see the dependencies used in project by running `./gradlew -q dependencies` [report](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies) for the project. Show what dependencies you have added and what errors you are getting.